# why a protected member is allowed in a C++ class marked as final?

Tags: c++, c++11

A similar question has been already asked in stackoverflow regarding Java.
But C++ does not behaves exactly as Java and, in particular, C++ does not allow access on protected members of a class "...from another package...".

So, what is the rational to allow protected members inside class marked as final ? Is a convenient way for the developer to quickly switch a class from final to non final (if the design change) ?

Comment: Don't you mean protected final method or const protected value?

Comment: You will probably have to interview a lot of people in the standards committee to answer this question. Chances are nobody made a compelling reason to forbid it and adding the `final` keyword to member functions just defaults to all member functions. In other words: It just happened.

Comment: Voted to close as **opinion based**. There *may* be an answer, if the question was ever brought up. But C++ allows a lot that doesn't make sense, e.g. multiple default constructors, because it would be unreasonable to explicitly disallow every case of nonsense consequences of the rules.

Comment: I say, it is a convenient way to quickly switch non-final class to final. Otherwise you will have to make all protected members private, potentially breaking ABI.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I disagree with the assessment of "opinion based". The OP is asking for specific diffs between Java and C++.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi As I read the question, OP is asking why it is permitted to have `protected` members in a `final` class in C++.    They only mentioned Java as background. It would be quite a different question to ask "What is the difference between `final` in Java and C++?".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  there's the *But C++ does not behaves exactly as Java and, in particular, C++ does not allow access on protected members of a class "...from another package...".* context in which the question is raised. Rather than interpret it as an opinion, one should see in it a misunderstanding of the specific differences between final in Java vs C++. Putting the Q onhold as opinion-based won't tell the OP "Buddy, you misunderstood"

Comment: C++ doesn't forbid things simply because they don't make sense, it forbids only things that either conflict with other things or those that are difficult or impossible to implement.

Comment: You are probably asking the question the wrong way - C++ has had protected members since always, and the proposal to add `final` didn't forbid adding `final` to classes with access specifiers.